# Cake 3: Generating default model for tests

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, cakephp-3.0

I know that CakePHP 3 is able to generate a TableClass when it doesn't exist.
But this isn't working in testing with the `getMockForModel()` method.

How will I be able to use a custom Table-class without creating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto-Tables are based on `\Cake\ORM\Table` instances, so what you can do is mock that class, just make sure that you pass the necessary options, that is at least `table` (name of the database table to represent), and most probably `connection` (the connection instance to use).

See **http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#___construct**

Something along the lines of:

```
$connection = ConnectionManager::get('test');

$table = $this->getMock('Cake\ORM\Table', ['methods', 'to', 'mock'], [
    ['table' => 'whatevers', 'connection' => $connection]
]);
```